# How do I resolve dependencies which are modules and have no relativePath in the POM?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-3

I'm working on a project where we are analysing dependency relationships in artifacts from Maven Central. What I need to do is extract the dependencies as GraphML using `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree` and for simple projects that's easy.

However, for projects which have `<module>` dependencies *but no `relativePath`* in the pom, I cannot get those dependencies resolved:

My example is the Apache Hivemind project pom, modules section:

```
<modules>
    <module>framework</module>
    <module>xml</module>
    <module>annotations</module>
    <module>library</module>
    <module>jmx</module>
    <module>examples</module>
</modules>
```

Which results in this output:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.hivemind:hivemind-project:2.0-alpha-1 (/data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/hivemind-project-2.0-alpha-1.pom) has 6 errors
[ERROR]     Child module /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/framework of /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/hivemind-project-2.0-alpha-1.pom does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/xml of /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/hivemind-project-2.0-alpha-1.pom does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/annotations of /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/hivemind-project-2.0-alpha-1.pom does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/library of /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/hivemind-project-2.0-alpha-1.pom does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/jmx of /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/hivemind-project-2.0-alpha-1.pom does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/examples of /data/scratch/artifacts/org/apache/hivemind/hivemind-project/2.0-alpha-1/hivemind-project-2.0-alpha-1.pom does not exist
```

I do have all those dependencies downloaded into my local repo.

How do I invoke mvn so that I can get it to look in my local repo (or any repo I specify, for that matter) for the dependencies?

Comment: If the `<relativePath>..</relativePath>` tag is not given it has a default value which is `../pom.xml` ? This is called convention over configuration.

Comment: You are correct, it does default to `../pom.xml`, however for the artifacts I've downloaded to check on, that filename never exists and mvn then assumes that each module exists as a subdir of the g/a/v I'm trying to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague suggested that I try a slightly different approach: make the artifact in the POM a dependency in a new (temporary) POM.

So for `org.apache.hivemind:hivemind-framework:2.0-alpha-1`, construct a temporary POM as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hivemind</groupId>
            <artifactId>hivemind-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and then use that temporary POM as the -f argument.